# Checking mongodb created connection

Tags: java, mongodb, database

I have java driver, created singleton instance to connect with mongodb.

```
Static{
MongoClientOptions.Builder builder = new    
MongoClientOptions.Builder().writeConcern(WriteConcern.JOURNALENABLED);

mongoObj = new MongoClient(ipAddress, builder.build());
}
```

My problem is that , since singleton is there only one connection to mongodb should be created but mongostat is showing 1000 connections created.

I tried with `db.currentOp(true)` and `db.serverStatus()` connections but didn't tell much about it.

Comment: Where are you getting the 1000 number from? Do you mean 100? Opening a `MongoClient` causes the driver to create a connection pool, not just one connection, so that the `MongoClient` can be used by the entire application. I believe the default max size of the pool is 100. What activity is your application doing when you see a lot of connections?

Comment: @ wdberkeley. I can see 1000 connections in mongostat. My application is logging app. So different applications are hitting a webservice, which is having singelton (Above written code) and data is inserted using this webservice to mongodb. After running for few days I find connections are increasing and reached upto 1000

Comment: Behind the scenes MongoClient uses a connection pool to connect to MongoDB - the default maximum connections per host is 100.  See http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.0/com/mongodb/MongoClientOptions.Builder.html#connectionsPerHost-int-

In the webservice do you have 10 workers?  That could account for the it getting upto 1000 connections.

Comment: @Ross Its called inside static. Do you think it still create new connection, even if I have 100 worker thread for webservice? Anyway, I have only single thread.